# SSRS 2008 IE11 content Overlapp

Tags: internet-explorer, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

There are many IE 11 SSRS compatibility issues reported. However I can't find any similar to mine:

- rectangle not auto-stretched.
- content following are not auto-positioned.

Better show than say.
[image]

Comment: there are always a lot of issues seeing reports in browsers, generating the pdf _(s)_ is always a better idea

Comment: @lrf like the idea, will try.

Answer (score 0):

Rectangle of SSRS 2008 R2, not expanding with its content (tablixes) in IE 9+. Don't know why. But here is the solution if anyone runs into similar problem:

Remove rectangle, format tablixes, give corresponding border a style from "none".

Details:

1. Cut-n-paste all tablixes to outside somewhere in the report to
   preserve everything to avoid having to re-creating them.
2. Select and delete the rectangle.
3. Replace all tablixes back to where they were.
4. Go properties, border, my case, give "solid" for left and right
   borders to all, and top border for the top one, bottom border for
   the bottom one.

One small catch, the bottom border never shows up, and can't use a simple line append to the bottom one either. However, it solves most of the problem.